# Beyond Many to Many. How to get data which isn't directly related to the pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between an article/blog and it's category. There is no direct relationship with a username.

Now I want to retrieve a list of blogs based on the given category. however I don't know how to get the username from the existing many to many relation between an article and a category.

Database relationships:

user:
Userid
Username

categories:
id
title

blogs:
id
title

blog_category:
id
blog_id
category_id

I have tried to use the eloquent method 'user()' of the blogs class within the

```
$category = Category::with('blogs')->findOrFail($request['category']);
```

line, but that doesn't work, because it's the Category Model and not the Blog model.

Eloquent method within the Blog model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'blog_category');
}
```

Eloquent method within the Category model:

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blog', 'blog_category','category_id','blog_id');
}
```

Relevant Eloquent methods within the User model:

```
public function blog()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Blog::class, 'user_id');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
}
```

Show method of the CategoryController

```
public function show(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $category = Category::with('blogs')->findOrFail($request['category']);
    $blog = $category->blogs()->get();
    return view('blog.category', compact('category','blog','user'));
}
```

I assumed that Laravel automatically gave me the option to get $blog->user from the existing relation between a blog and a user. But it doesn't let me, because I start from within the Category object. How can I use the Eloquent method in Blog model in relation to the Category Model?

Comment: `Category::with('blogs.user')`, then you can access the user

Comment: Check the `Many to many through` relationship. It "links" two models through another intermediate model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through